# Remove .htpasswd protection from a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have protected my root folder using .htpasswd

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /home/a1199104/public_html/.htpasswd
Require user lamak
```

The above code deny access to my whole site/folder/subfolder, I have a subfolder **public** It has some public files .I want anyone to access this folder and files without password protection, is this possible.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SetEnv and Order directive to remove password protection :

Try :

```
#set env variable noauth if uri is "/public/files"
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/public/ noauth=1

#auth
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /home/a1199104/public_html/.htpasswd
Require user lamak

 #Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require user lamak
Allow from env=noauth
```

Comment: Thanks starkeen it works  example.com/public/anyfile.php, but when i go to example.com/public without a slash in end ,it asked me for login why?

Comment: That is because our SetEnvIf directive sets the env variable **noauth** only when it matchs the request uri string starting with **/public** and a **/** . it fails to match uri string with **/public** . you can remove the trailing **/** from  setenvIf pattern **^/public/**  to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called `public/.htaccess` and place this code:

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
Satisfy any
```